# Chain rule for scalar-valued function with tensor argument

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, tensors, classical-mechanics, chain-rule

my question comes from continuum Mechanics, where we have the so-called deformation gradient $F$, which essentially is the Jacobian map of a transformation $x$. Then define $C=F^TF$ to be the right Cauchy-Green strain tensor. And finally we have a function $\sigma(F^TF)$ which is scalar valued.

**Question:** I need to take the derivative w.r.t. $F$ of $\sigma(F^TF)$, so of course I need to apply the chain rule: $$[D_F \sigma(F^TF)]_{ij} = \frac{\partial \sigma(C)}{\partial C_{kl}} \frac{\partial C_{kl}}{\partial F_{ij}}$$

and then I have that $\frac{\partial C_{kl}}{\partial F_{ij}}=\frac{\partial F_{mk} F_{ml}}{\partial F_{ij}} = \delta_{ij} \delta_{jk}F_{ml} + F_{mk} \delta_{im}\delta_{jl}$

However, I think that the result of the whole operation should be something like $D_C \sigma(C) F^T$, but I am really stuck! Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In coordinates, we have :
$$\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial F_{ij}}= \frac{ \partial\sigma}{\partial C_{kl}} \cdot \left( \delta_{jk}F_{il} + F_{ik}\delta_{jl}\right) = F_{il} \frac{ \partial\sigma}{\partial C_{jl}} + F_{ik}\frac{ \partial\sigma}{\partial C_{kj}} $$

The synthetic notation for this is :
$$D_F\sigma = F \cdot (D_C\sigma)^T + F\cdot D_C\sigma$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think there should be a $\cdot$ in your last equality. Also, it turns out that $D_C\sigma$ is symmetric...is there any chance to gain a factor $2$ @SolubleFish

Comment: The dot was meant to represent matrix multiplication (ie once contracted tensor product).  I corrected a mistake. It is now clear how you get a factor $2$ if $D_C\sigma$ is symmetric

Comment: It's clear, thanks a lot. Basically, I was on the right track, but then I got lost with the Kronecker deltas. Why did you chose to assume $m=i$ so to remain with only with one $\delta$ per summation term?  I was going to set immediately $m=i$ and $j=k$. @SolubleFish

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\s{\sigma}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Given the variable definitions
$$C = F^TF,\quad\quad \s = \s(C),\quad\quad G=\grad{\s}{C}$$
Note that since $C$ is symmetric, the gradient is too: $\;G=G^T$

Use the known gradient to write the differential. Then perform a change of variable from $C\to F.\,$ Then recover the new gradient.
$$\eqalign{
d\s &= G:dC \\&= G:(F^TdF+dF^TF) \\&= (G^T+G):F^TdF \\&= 2FG:dF \\
\grad{\s}{F} &= 2FG \\
\\
}$$

---

In the steps above, a colon is used to denote the matrix inner product, which is a convenient notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{AB^T} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such a product to be rearranged in many different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= A^TC:B = CB^T:A \\
}$$

Notice that higher-order tensors like $\LR{\grad{C_{k\ell}}{F_{ij}}}$ were not needed. This is true for most problems in Matrix Calculus.